# C++ - lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, function, class, variable-assignment, lvalue

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X 
{
    int i;
public:  
    X(int ii = 0);
};

X::X(int ii) { i = ii; }

int a;

X f1() { return X(); }
int f2() { return a; }

int main() {
    f1() = X(1);
    f2() = 3;
}
```

If you try to run it, you get

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

on line 17, therefore

> f1()

is considered a lvalue, while

> f2()

is not. An explanation would be of great help of how things work would be of great help.

Comment: f1() is not lvalue because f1 returns a copy. read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category
for move info.

Comment: I hope it's clear why you cannot assign to the temporary `int`, if it's not, I'll add another dupe for that.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen I'm alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `f1()` is considered a lvalue

No, what `f1` returns is still an rvalue (same as `f2`; more precisely it's a [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue)). But for class type, `f1() = X(1);` is just interpreted as `f1().operator=(X(1));`, which is pretty fine even though it might not make much sense; the temporary object returned by `f1()` will be destroyed soon. In short, you could call member functions on an rvalue with class type.

On the other hand, the similar behavior for built-in type is forbidden directly; assignment to such temporary doesn't make sense at all. That's why the compiler complains that it's not an lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

`f1()` returns an rvalue. You have to return a reference (lvalue) to allow you to do this assignment

Change

```
int f2() { return a; }
```

to

```
int& f2() {  return a; }
   ^
```

---

`f1()` returns rvalue but as instance of class `f1() = X(1);` calls assignment operator of class `f1().operator=(X(1));` which is alright.

Read more about [value categories here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Comment: "How to make it work" is not the question though.